# $ rails db fails with error, but database is working fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sockets, rails-postgresql

My Rails 3.2 app is using a PostgreSQL database. It's working great locally. I can migrate and interact with the application through the browser or irb.

However when I run `$ rails db`, I get an error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

My Postgres socket is actually located at: `/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432`

So how can I tell rails to look for it there when I use `$ rails db`

Comment: Have you filled `database.yml`?

Comment: Did you try `socket` variable in `database.yml`? Something like `socket: /var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432`

Comment: @ShamirK. As I state in my question, I can migrate and interact with the database which I obviously wouldn't be able to do if I didn't have a working database.yml

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev Good suggestion, but I've already tried that. It makes no difference. I don't understand how the rest of Rails can interact with the database, but `$ rails db` doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that you can interact with the app through `irb`. Does `rails console` work?